# ¿Cómo enviar un objeto en un atributo de tipo value de un option?

Tags: reactjs, select, map

Me explico, tengo el siguiente código :

```
const [info,setInfo] = useState([])

const handleInfo = (e) =>{
        setInfo(e.target.value)
}

<select class="custom-select" size="3000" onChange={handleInfo}>
                {resultados.map((item)=>(
                    <option  value={item}>{`${item.date} ${item.hour}`}</option>
                ))}
    
 </select>
```

Tengo un select, donde listo los resultados de un consulta a una base de datos, pero requiero la información completa cuando el usuario le de click a algún resultado de la lista para poder mostrar mas detalladamente la información de este item (amplitud,latitud ,frecuencia...etc),
pero si quiero obtener la información del item seleccionado, este es un string con el nombre [object object]; quisiera saber si es posible enviar el item como un objeto para poder sacar todo lo necesario de el y no como un string, si esto es posible o si no saber si hay algún parámetro diferente para guardar información como quisiera.

Comment: Puedes incluir como la data que tiene la variable _resultado_?

Comment: no te entendí amigo que preguntas jajajaja, pero en fin ya resolví mi duda y es que no se puede hacer lo que trataba, pero igual encontré otra forma de resolverlo, de igual forma agradezco tu comentario intentando ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Es normal que te salga eso de resultado estas tratando de pasar como valor un objeto, y jsx admite un string, además falta el atributo key para listar, faltaría añadir otro componente que se muestre cuando selecciones.

Comment: No listar si lista correctamente, pero si efectivamente no se puede enviar un objeto por un value y eso mas que nada esa era mi pregunta en si, que si eso era posible y no lo era, igual lo solucione de otra forma que mejor ni explico por que es muy puntual para mi problema xD